# $\delta_0$ in Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I'm reading a one proof. This say

If $u$ is a test function (smooth function with compact support), then 
$$|\delta_0(u)|=|u(0)|=\left|\int_{—1}^0u'(t)dt\right|\leq \lVert u'\rVert_p\leq \lVert u\rVert_{W^{1,p}(-1,1)}.$$
By density of test function, we can extend $\delta_0$ to the functions of $W^{1,p}(-1,1)$.

I don't understand this "By density of test function, we can extend $\delta_0$ to the functions of $W^{1,p}(-1,1)$".

Please, Anybody will be able to explain me?

Comment: It means that the test function space $C^{\infty}_c(I)$ is dense in $W^{1,p}_0(I)$ which is a closed subspace of $W^{1,p}(I)$.

Comment: but Why "we can extend $\delta_0$ to the functions of $W^{-1,p}(-1,1)$"?

Comment: $W^{-1,p}$ is the space of bounded linear functional on $W^{1,p}_0$, aka the dual space of $W^{1,p}_0$, please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think your interpretation on this topic sounds inaccurate to me, without context I am guessing the author meant to convey the idea

> "Dirac delta, as a distribution, is a bounded linear functional in $W^{1,p}_0(I)$"

To establish this, simply using the definition $\delta_0[u] = u(0)$ doesn't make any sense for $u\in W^{1,p}(I)$ for $u$ can be any number on a measure zero set, think how we circumvent this to define the trace of function in a Sobolev space to make the boundary value problem meaningful.

Therefore we would like to establish this indirectly borrowing the test function space $C^{\infty}_c(I)$, which is dense in $W^{1,p}_0(I)$ under the norm $\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,p}}$. The boundedness of $\delta_0[\cdot]$ in $W^{1,p}_0(I)$ is established by the inequality you gave and so-called "density argument":

> $\forall u\in W^{1,p}_0(I)$, choose $\phi_n\in C^{\infty}_c(I)$, and $\phi_n\to u$ under $\|\cdot\|_{W^{1,p}}$, define $\delta_0[u] = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\delta_0[\phi_n]$, then $\delta_0[\cdot]$ is a bounded linear functional in $W^{1,p}_0(I)$.

Comment: the question is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208906/delta-dirac-function/208915#208915, sorry the Sobolev space is $W^{-1,p}$

Comment: @user46060 this is same with what I wrote, $W^{-1,p}$ is the same with the space of bounded linear functional in $W^{1,p}_0$.